# Twilio accept incoming call

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to allow users to accept incoming calls but I can't get it to work. This is what I have tried. If it is an incoming call, it will pause for 20 seconds. The user can then choose to accept the call on the client side which will invoke /answerCall

I would appreciate any tips/suggestions on whether I am on the right track or not. Thank you!

```html
 server.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
    if (request.body.Direction == "inbound") {
      const responser = new VoiceResponse();
      responser.say('I will pause 10 seconds starting now!');
      responser.pause({
          length: 20
      });
      io.sockets.emit("incoming call", request.body)
      responser.say('I just paused 10 seconds');
      response.setHeader('content-type', 'text/xml');
      response.send(responser.toString());
    }
  });
```

```html
  server.post('/answerCall', (request, response) => {
    console.log("answered call: " + request.body.id);
    console.log("caller is: " + request.body.caller);
    client.calls(request.body.id).update({
      url: 'https://5131-108-24-86-148.ngrok.io/routeCall',
      method: 'POST'
    })
  })
```

```html
  server.post('/routeCall', (request, response) => {
    const responser = new VoiceResponse();
    const dial = responser.dial({ callerId: '+16672268690' });
    dial.number({
      statusCallbackEvent: 'initiated ringing answered completed',
      statusCallback: 'https://5131-108-24-86-148.ngrok.io/statuscallback',
      statusCallbackMethod: 'POST'
    }, request.body.From);

    response.setHeader('content-type', 'text/xml');
    response.send(responser.toString())
  })
```